# App Engine - Task Queue Retry Count with Mapper API

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce, task-queue

here is what I'm trying to do:
I set up a MapReduce job with the new Mapper API. This basically works fine.
The problem is that the Task Queue retries all tasks that have failed. But actually I don't want him to do that. 
Is there a way to delete a task from the queue or tell it that the task was completed successfully? Perhaps passing a 200 status code?

I know that I can fetch the X-Appengine-Taskretrycount, but that doesn't really help since I don't know how to stop the task. I tried using a 'pass' in the try .. except block but that didn't work either.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Can't you modify your mapper so it doesn't fail, instead? Alternately, use something other than mapreduce, since the mapreduce framework is built around the assumption that you want to reliably update every matching entity.

Comment: Hey Nick,
I'm using urlfetch in the mapper to retrieve some information, so there is always the chance of getting a timeout. If I'm able to retrieve the info I set a flag and vice versa if the fetch fails. So the mapper actually does exactly what I want him to do and I'm quite satisfied with that.
The only problem is really the task queue that then keeps on retrying failed fetches.

Comment: Addition (since I cannot edit my former comment): What you are proposing is actually exactly what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to treat the timeout not as a failure but a valid response for the task that is executed.

Comment: the "pass" keyword in python does nothing.  it is only a syntax placeholder for a line where code is expected but you don't want to do anything, such as try: # some code  except: pass     If you don't have the word "pass" there the interpreter will expect code to be under it and indented which won't actually be there and will throw an exception you don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your task handler do this

```
class yourTaskWorker(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        logging.info('yourTaskWorker (post)...')        
        if int(self.request.headers['X-Appengine-Taskretrycount']) == 0:
            logging.info('running task...')
            # call whatever functions you want here
        else:
            logging.info('this task failed before, not going to retry.')
            # obviously call nothing here, the task will "pass" without error and go away
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: You can also throw a `deferred.PermanentTaskFailure` exception, which will prevent appengine from retrying and report an exception in the console.

Answer (score 2):

As of http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/source/detail?r=114 change, context object has task_retry_count attribute.