# AppEngine MapReduce NDB, DeadlineExceededError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce, app-engine-ndb

we're trying to heavily use **MapReduce** in our project. 
Now we have this problem, there is a lots of '**DeadlineExceededError**' errors in the log...

One example of it ( traceback differs each time a bit ) :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 207, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sba/1.362471299468574812/mapreduce/base_handler.py", line 65, in post
    self.handle()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sba/1.362471299468574812/mapreduce/handlers.py", line 208, in handle
    ctx.flush()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sba/1.362471299468574812/mapreduce/context.py", line 333, in flush
    pool.flush()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sba/1.362471299468574812/mapreduce/context.py", line 221, in flush
    self.__flush_ndb_puts()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sba/1.362471299468574812/mapreduce/context.py", line 239, in __flush_ndb_puts
    ndb.put_multi(self.ndb_puts.items, config=self.__create_config())
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3625, in put_multi
    for future in put_multi_async(entities, **ctx_options)]
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 323, in get_result
    self.check_success()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 318, in check_success
    self.wait()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 302, in wait
    if not ev.run1():
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/eventloop.py", line 219, in run1
    delay = self.run0()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/eventloop.py", line 181, in run0
    callback(*args, **kwds)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 365, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.send(val)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py", line 274, in _put_tasklet
    keys = yield self._conn.async_put(options, datastore_entities)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1560, in async_put
    for pbs, indexes in pbsgen:
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1350, in __generate_pb_lists
    incr_size = pb.lengthString(pb.ByteSize()) + 1
DeadlineExceededError
```

**My questions are:**

- How can we avoid this Error?
- What happens with the job, does it get retried (if so how can we control it?) or not ?
- Does it causes data inconsistency in the end ?

Comment: Are you doing too much work in one step?

Comment: seems so ;) now we're testing that batch_size, and it seems to be helping. A bit more testing needed and I might accept dragonx answer.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you are doing too many puts than it is possible to insert in one datastore call. You have multiple options here:

1. If this is a relatively rare event - ignore it. Mapreduce will retry the slice and will lower put pool size. Make sure that your map is idempotent.
2. Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/source/browse/trunk/python/src/mapreduce/context.py - in your main.py you can lower `DATASTORE_DEADLINE`, `MAX_ENTITY_COUNT` or `MAX_POOL_SIZE` to lower the size of the pool for the whole mapreduce.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an InputReader, you might be able to adjust the default batch_size to reduce the number of entities processed by each task.

I believe the task queue will retry tasks, but you probably don't want it to, since it'll likley hit the same DeadlineExceededError.

Data inconsistencies are possible.

See this question as well.
[App Engine - Task Queue Retry Count with Mapper API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342072/app-engine-task-queue-retry-count-with-mapper-api)