# AppEngine MapReduce NDB, Repeated InternalError: internal error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce, app-engine-ndb

We're trying to heavily use **MapReduce** in our project. Now we have this problem, there are a lot of **'InternalError: internal error.'** errors in the log...

**One example of it:**

```
    "POST /mapreduce/worker_callback HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "http://appname/mapreduce/worker_callback" "AppEngine-Google; 
(+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "appname.appspot.com" ms=18856 cpu_ms=15980 
queue_name=default task_name=appengine-mrshard-15828822618486744D69C-11-195 
instance=00c61b117c47e0cba49bc5e5c7f9d328693e95ce
W 2012-10-24 06:51:27.140
suspended generator _put_tasklet(context.py:274) raised InternalError(internal error.)
W 2012-10-24 06:51:27.153
suspended generator put(context.py:703) raised InternalError(internal error.)
E 2012-10-24 06:51:27.207
internal error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~appname/1.362664407983567993/mapreduce/base_handler.py", line 65, in post
    self.handle()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~appname/1.362664407983567993/mapreduce/handlers.py", line 208, in handle
    ctx.flush()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~appname/1.362664407983567993/mapreduce/context.py", line 333, in flush
    pool.flush()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~appname/1.362664407983567993/mapreduce/context.py", line 221, in flush
    self.__flush_ndb_puts()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~appname/1.362664407983567993/mapreduce/context.py", line 239, in __flush_ndb_puts
    ndb.put_multi(self.ndb_puts.items, config=self.__create_config())
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3650, in put_multi
    for future in put_multi_async(entities, **ctx_options)]
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 325, in get_result
    self.check_success()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 368, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py", line 703, in put
    key = yield self._put_batcher.add(entity, options)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 368, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py", line 274, in _put_tasklet
    keys = yield self._conn.async_put(options, datastore_entities)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 454, in _on_rpc_completion
    result = rpc.get_result()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 834, in get_result
    result = rpc.get_result()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 604, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1569, in __put_hook
    self.check_rpc_success(rpc)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1224, in check_rpc_success
    raise _ToDatastoreError(err)
InternalError: internal error.
```

**queue.yaml:**

```
queue:
- name: default
  rate: 500/s
  bucket_size: 100
  max_concurrent_requests: 400
  retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 5
    max_backoff_seconds: 120
    max_doublings: 2
```

**MapReduce mapper params:**

```
'shard_count': 16,
'processing_rate': 200,
'batch_size': 20
 we would like to increase these numbers, since we need more speed in processing, but once we try to increase it increases error rate...
```

**Blobstore Files Count:** several ( some of them contain millions of lines )

**Frontend Instance Class:** F4

**Processing flow:**

1. We use only mapper for this particular processing.
2. We user BlobstoreLineInputReader (blob contains text file).
3. Each line represents new entry we need to create if it does not exist already(some of them we update).

**My questions are:**

- How can we avoid these errors?
- Are there any tips/hints on how we can choose/balance mapper params (shard_count, processing_rate, batch_size) ?
- What happens with the job, does it get
  retried (if so, how can we control it?) or not ?

BTW, we tried to play with some of the suggestions provided [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910282/appengine-mapreduce-ndb-deadlineexceedederror) (control batch_size) but we still see this.

Comment: Did you get to solve this?, I am seeing a lot of these today triggered by my taskqueues.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a timeout error - check you logs to see how long that process is running before that happens.

If it is, you should try reducing the number of items that you're calling put_multi() on (ie reduce your batch size) and adding a timer check so that when your average time per put_multi() call gets close to the process time limit you quit and let another one start.